# Сформировать массив внутри перебора reduce es6 Javascript

Tags: javascript, объекты, ecmascript-6, map, filter

Есть массив объектов

```
  [
  {
    "id": 96,
    "NAME": "Алексей Никашкин",
    "PRODUCT": "BMK-60-3DU (до 60 кВт, подкл. котла G 1″, 1+1+1 контура G ¾″)",
    "WELD_LENGTH": "300",
    "DATE": "01.04.2019",
    "DATE_TIMESTAMP": 1554066000,
    "QUANTITY": "1"
  },
  {
    "id": 97,
    "NAME": "Алексей Никашкин",
    "PRODUCT": "BMK-60-4D (до 60 кВт, подкл. котла G 1″, 3+1 контура G ¾″)",
    "WELD_LENGTH": "400",
    "DATE": "02.04.2019",
    "DATE_TIMESTAMP": 1554066000,
    "QUANTITY": "3"
  },
  {
    "id": 98,
    "NAME": "Алексей Морозов",
    "PRODUCT": "BMK-60-5DU (до 60 кВт, подкл. котла G 1″, 2+2+1 контура G ¾″)",
    "WELD_LENGTH": "500",
    "DATE": "02.04.2019",
    "DATE_TIMESTAMP": 1554066000,
    "QUANTITY": "5"
  },      {
    "id": 99,
    "NAME": "Алексей Морозов",
    "PRODUCT": "BMK-60-5DU (до 60 кВт, подкл. котла G 1″, 2+2+1 контура G ¾″)",
    "WELD_LENGTH": "500",
    "DATE": "03.04.2019",
    "DATE_TIMESTAMP": 1554066000,
    "QUANTITY": "3"
  }
]
```

UPDATED:
Хочется получить массив объектов вида:

```
[
  {
    "date": ["01.04.2019", "02.04.2019", "03.04.2019"],
    "name": "Алексей Морозов"
  },
  {
    "date": ["01.04.2019", "02.04.2019", "03.04.2019"],
    "name": "Алексей Никашкин"
  }
]
```

Но получаю в таком виде:

```
{
  "Алексей Морозов": {
    "label": "Алексей Морозов",
    "data": [
      "02.04.2019",
      "03.04.2019",
      "01.04.2019",
      "04.04.2019",
      "05.04.2019"
    ]
  },
  "Алексей Никашкин": {
    "label": "Алексей Никашкин",
    "data": [
      "02.04.2019",
      "01.04.2019",
      "03.04.2019",
      "04.04.2019",
      "05.04.2019"
    ]
  }
}
```

Проблема в том что ключами родительских объектов являются имена -
`},
  "Алексей Никашкин": {
    "label": "Алексей Никашкин",
    "data": [
      "02.04.2019",
      "01.04.2019",
      "03.04.2019",
      "04.04.2019",
      "05.04.2019"
    ]
  }`, а мне нужно получить просто массив объектов Друг за другом. Экспортирую в chart.js

Пример кода:

```
        let data  = rows.reduce(function(result, value){
            let name = value['NAME'];
            let date = value['DATE'];

            if(!result.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
                result[name] = { label: name, data: [] };
            }
            /* Записали даты в массив */
            result[name].data.push(date);
            /* Оставили только уникальные значения */
            result[name].data = Array.from(new Set([...result[name].data]));
            return result;
        }, {});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При добавлении нового человека создаете объект с именем и пустым масивом дат. И потом просто пополняете этот массив.

```js
var data=[{"id":96,"NAME":"Алексей Никашкин","DATE":"01.04.2019",},{"id":97,"NAME":"Алексей Никашкин","DATE":"02.04.2019",},{"id":98,"NAME":"Алексей Морозов","DATE":"02.04.2019",},{"id":99,"NAME":"Алексей Морозов","DATE":"03.04.2019",}, {"id":100,"NAME":"Алексей Морозов","DATE":"03.04.2019",}];

var result  = data.reduce(function(acc, v){
                     let name = v.NAME;
                     if(! (name in acc) ) {
                         acc[name] = { name: name, dates: [] };
                     } 
                     if( acc[name].dates.indexOf(v.date) == -1){
                         acc[name].dates.push(v.DATE);
                     }
                     
                     return acc;
                  }, {});

result = Object.keys(result).map( k => result[k] );

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, но если будет выборка из повторяющихся дат, либо из большого массива дат - они будут дублироваться.
 '{
  "Алексей Морозов": {
    "name": "Алексей Морозов",
    "dates": [
      "02.04.2019",
      "02.04.2019",
      "02.04.2019",
      "01.04.2019",
      "01.04.2019",
      "02.04.2019",
      "02.04.2019",
    ]
  },
  "Алексей Никашкин": {
    "name": "Алексей Никашкин",
    "dates": [
      "02.04.2019",
      "01.04.2019",
      "01.04.2019",
      "01.04.2019",
      "02.04.2019",
      "02.04.2019",
    ]
  }
}'

Comment: @Николай такие "если" необходимо в вопросе писать сразу. проверяйте содержит ли массив значение, прежде чем добавлять. `if(acc[name].dates.indexOf(v.DATE) == -1) ...`

Comment: Обновил описание задачи.
А возможно ли сформировать массив объектов без ключей? 

следующего вида:
`{
  {
    "date": ["01.04.2019", "02.04.2019", "03.04.2019"],
    "name": "Алексей Морозов"
  },
  {
    "date": ["01.04.2019", "02.04.2019", "03.04.2019"],
    "name": "Алексей Никашкин"
  }
}`

Comment: @Николай добавить `result = Object.keys(result).map( k => result[k]);`. Замечу, что фигурные скобки это объект, квадратные это массив, а то кажется у вас понятия путаются. в массиве нет ключей, там индексы целочисленные. Форма приведенная вам выше это синтаксическая ошибка. массив объекто выглядит как `[ {..}, {..}, ...]`

Comment: 1. Да, я имею ввиду массив объектов, по невнимательности указал фигурные вместо квадратных скобок.
2. код `result = Object.keys(result).map( k => result[k]);` к сожалению возвращает все обратно и дублирует имена.
`[
  {
    "label": "Алексей Морозов",
    "data": [
      "01.04.2019"
    ]
  },
  {
    "label": "Алексей Морозов",
    "data": [
      "02.04.2019"
    ]
  },
  {
    "label": "Алексей Никашкин",
    "data": [
      "03.04.2019"
    ]
  },
]`

Comment: @Николай ну хз. у меня ничего не дублирует. код дополнил, дублирующую дату даже добавил

Comment: @teran, `Object.keys(result).map( k => result[k])` -> `Object.values(result)`

Comment: @Grundy нет его в ES6

Comment: @teran, подозреваю метка [tag:ecmascript-6] здесь не для ограничения сверху, а для ограничения снизу :)